Conditional Image in AGOL Web Map Pop-Up
In an AGOl web map, I want an externally-hosted image to appear in a pop-up when a feature has a certain value. In this case, when LocCon_Labels = "BC P".
In the pop-ups options, I have gone to "+ Add Content" and selected "Arcade" and used this code:
var output;
if (Lower($feature.LocCon_Labels) == "BC P") output = '<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/pTzCMSBV/bc-provenance.png" alt="Image">'

return { 
    type : 'text', 
    text : output
}

This is returning the image link text, not the image.
How can I change the code to display the image itself?

That's curious. This code works properly in my popup
var output;
if ($feature.PhotoCount > 0) output = '<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/pTzCMSBV/bc-provenance.png" alt="Image">'

return {
  type: "text",
  text: output
};


However, you won't get an output with your code. Lower($feature.LocCon_Labels) == "BC P" will never evaluate as true, since Lower($feature.LocCon_Labels) will return "bc p"
